# Ross Analysis Question 4.10 (using archimedean property)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Ross defines the Archimedean Property as follows:

> If $a>0$ and $b>0$ , then for some integer $n$, we have $na>b$.

Here is problem 4.10:

> Prove that if $a>0$ , then there exists $n$ (element of natural numbers)
>   such that $\frac{1}{n}< a < n$ .

**Solution:** We consider two cases:

*Case 1*: $a>1$ , then since $a>0 $we can choose a positive integer $n$ such that $a < n$. From $a< n$ we deduce that $\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{n}$ and because $a>1$ we have $a>\frac{1}{a}$, hence $a>\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore $\frac{1}{n}< a < n$.

*Case 2:* $0 < a < 1$. Then since $a>0$ we can choose a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}< a$. From $\frac{1}{n}< a$ we deduce that $n>\frac{1}{a}$  and because $0< a < 1$ we have $\frac{1}{a}>a$ , hence $n >a$ .Therefore $\frac{1}{n}< a < n$.

I have seen a shorter proof online, I am only asking if my solution is correct.

Comment: Please format your question properly using Latex.

Comment: I'm going to quibble.  How do you know you can find a positive integer $n$ so that $a < n$?  What if $a$ is an upper bound of the natural numbers?  Do you know that the natural numbers are unbounded?

Comment: Did you use the archimedian property? If so where?  If not why not?

Comment: And how do you know there is an $n$ so that $\frac 1n < a$?  What if $a$ is a positive lower bound of $K=\{\frac 1n| n\in \mathbb Z\}$?  Do we know whether or not $K$ is bounded below? Do you know that it is not? If it is do you know that $\inf K$ is non-positive?... (It seems to me you are actually assuming what you are supposed to be proving.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems perfectly fine to me. However, you are missing the case $a=1$; of course this is trivial as for $a=1$ then any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ strictly greater than $1$ satisfies $\frac{1}{n} < a < n$, but one should include this in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are assuming what you are trying to prove.

How do you know that there exists an $n$ so that $a < n$?  And how do you know there exists and $n$ so that $\frac 1n < a$?

I think you are supposed to use the archmediean principle. Let $\beta = a$ and let $\alpha = 1$ so there exists an $n$ so that $n\alpha > \beta$.  i.e. $n\cdot 1 > a$.

Proving there is an $n$ so that $\frac 1n < a$ requires a twist in proving that there is an $n > \frac 1a$ but that's the same thing.  By AP there is an $n$ so that $n\cdot 1 > \frac 1a$.

Comment: I cannot understand your comment , in the online solution it says that there exists positive integers n(1) and n(2) such that (1/n(1))<a and a<n(2) then we put n=max {n(1), n(2)}